pinescript v5 alert keeps triggering despite the flag
i have a pine script code where I need an alert to fire once per bar without depending on the alert frequency once per bar. so I used a flag that should reset at the beginning of each bar to allow only one alert.
no matter what i do it keeps triggering tens of times per bar.
Also i need to draw a line once per bar and don't change it's location with every change in life bars.
The code keeps changing the line each time the price change
here is the code
//@version=5
indicator("Bar States", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)
//indicator("Bar States", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)
condition1 = close > open
//condition1 = close > open

// Variables to track alerts
var bool alerted = false

if barstate.isnew
    // Reset the alerted flag at the start of each new bar
    alerted := false

if condition1 and not alerted
    if barstate.isrealtime
        // In live trading, trigger alert as soon as the condition is met, without waiting for the bar to close
        line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index + 1, close, color=color.orange, width=3)
        alert("close up", alert.freq_all)
        alerted := true

will be great if someone can help as this language is driving me crazy with this unexpected behaviours
thank you
i tried flags, different nesting of the if cond etc

Take a look at the varip variable declaration, I guess this will solve your problem, example here

A Pine script - by default - runs once, immediately after a candle is closed. The other mode is when the script runs on every tick.
To change the default behavior, add calc_on_every_tick = true to the  indicator() definition.
But my suggestion (I have been there), don't do that until you get familiar with the Pine engine, use a lower time frame instead, like 5 minutes/1 minute.
